# Using gdb with make

Tags: c, makefile, gdb

I want to use gdb with my application for debug throught all the libraries. I use `make` for compile the application, and if I try gdb it says `no debugging symbols found`.

How I can modify my makefile for use `-g` flag?

```
hospital: hospital.o config.o utils.o message.o semaphore.o sharedmem.o logger.o
    gcc -o hospital hospital.o config.o utils.o message.o semaphore.o sharedmem.o logger.o
hospital.o: hospital.c
    gcc -c hospital.c
sharedmem.o: sharedmem.c sharedmem.h
    gcc -c sharedmem.c
message.o: message.c message.h
    gcc -c message.c
semaphore.o: semaphore.c semaphore.h
    gcc -c semaphore.c
config.o: config.c config.h
    gcc -c config.c
logger.o: logger.c logger.h
    gcc -c logger.c
utils.o: utils.c utils.h
    gcc -c utils.c
clean:
    rm -f *.o
```

Comment: You should use `$(CFLAGS)` in your makefile, so you can easily add flags to all the compilations.

Comment: How is gdb related to your Makefile? Just use the correct compiler options. And use variables or automatic targets. Your Makefile already is hard to maintain.

Comment: @Olaf That's his question: how does he add the correct compiler options so he can use gdb?

Comment: @Barmar: Still not related to Makefile, but to compiler options. I'd recommend OP should research the basics of compilation. (And take a short beginner's tutorial for make, but that is not directly related)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to what you're asking, is to add the '-g' switch when you compile the object files, i.e.

```
hospital: hospital.o config.o utils.o message.o semaphore.o sharedmem.o     logger.o
    gcc -o hospital hospital.o config.o utils.o message.o semaphore.o     sharedmem.o logger.o
hospital.o: hospital.c
    gcc -g -c hospital.c
sharedmem.o: sharedmem.c sharedmem.h
    gcc -g -c sharedmem.c
message.o: message.c message.h
    gcc -g -c message.c
semaphore.o: semaphore.c semaphore.h
    gcc -g -c semaphore.c
config.o: config.c config.h
    gcc -g -c config.c
logger.o: logger.c logger.h
    gcc -g -c logger.c
utils.o: utils.c utils.h
    gcc -g -c utils.c
clean:
    rm -f *.o
```

But, a Makefile like this is really hard to maintain. Make can do a lot of this stuff for you, check out [this example](https://gist.github.com/reecer/11065346) which should work well for your project. Simply add '-g' to the CFLAGS variable.

Even something smaller, like this, would do what you want:

```
PROGRAM := hostpital
SRCS := $(wildcard *.c)
OBJS := ${SRCS:.c=.o}
CFLAGS=-g

$(PROGRAM): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) -o $(PROGRAM)

clean:
    @- $(RM) $(PROGRAM)
    @- $(RM) $(OBJS)
```

**NOTE:**
Makefile needs tabs preceding the actions. Replace leading spaces with a tab.

Comment: make `Makefile:7: *** missing separator.  Stop.`

Comment: Makefile needs tabs preceding the targets. Remove the 4 spaces preceding the line under `$(PROGRAM):`, replace with a tab. And do the same with the 2 lines under `clean:`. I couldn't figure out how to put a tab in the answer, editing box didn't let me.

Comment: This `Makefile` is an order of magnitude better than the original, but is still horrible as an example.

Answer (score 3):

Add the `-g` option to all the compilations.

```
hospital: hospital.o config.o utils.o message.o semaphore.o sharedmem.o logger.o
    gcc -o hospital hospital.o config.o utils.o message.o semaphore.o sharedmem.o logger.o
hospital.o: hospital.c
    gcc -g -c hospital.c
sharedmem.o: sharedmem.c sharedmem.h
    gcc -g -c sharedmem.c
message.o: message.c message.h
    gcc -g -c message.c
semaphore.o: semaphore.c semaphore.h
    gcc -g -c semaphore.c
config.o: config.c config.h
    gcc -g -c config.c
logger.o: logger.c logger.h
    gcc -g -c logger.c
utils.o: utils.c utils.h
    gcc -g -c utils.c
clean:
    rm -f *.o
```

But you would probably be better off using the [default rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html) for compiling, instead of entering all the `.c -> .o` actions explicitly. The default rules use `$(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS)`, which you can set on the command line. So when you want to compile with debugging enabled, you do:

```
make clean
make CFLAGS=-g hospital
```